# Can I include mongod.exe in my commercial destop based or user self hosted app withou open sourcing it?

Tags: licensing, commercial, mongodb

I have read the [doc](http://www.mongodb.org/about/licensing/) and the [apgl blog post](http://blog.mongodb.org/post/103832439/the-agpl), but I still have some concerns:
Can I include mongodb.exe in my commercial desktop based app? 
Can I include mongodb.exe in my commercial user self hosted web app？

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read the web page.  It says:

> The goal of the server license is to require that enhancements to
>   MongoDB be released to the community. Traditional GPL often does not
>   achieve this anymore as a huge amount of software runs in the cloud.
>   For example, Google has no obligation to release their improvements to
>   the MySQL kernel – if they do they are being nice.
>
> To make the above practical, we promise that your client application
>   which uses the database is a separate work. To facilitate this, the
>   mongodb.org supported drivers (the part you link with your
>   application) are released under Apache license, which is copyleft
>   free.

Seems pretty clear to me.

Personally, if I were MongoDB, I would have simply written my own license that states their intent in plain English, rather than trying to tack on a highly-restrictive license like AGPL, and then provide exceptions.

Comment: English is not my mother language. So, both my question's answer are yes then?

Comment: It says "We're AGPL licensed, but all we really want is, if you improve MongoDB, share your improvements."  That's how I read it.  It also says that the database drivers are not AGPL, so you can use them freely under the Apache License.